# Python configure logging format from one place

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to set my log format (and loglevel) in one place for a multi-module app.

My app structure is:

```
myapp/
     |- __init__.py
     |- __main__.py
     \_ sub/
           |- foo.py
```

and I launch it with: `python -m myapp`

I've set up the logging in `__init__.py` as follows:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.info("Finished configuring logger()")
```

Here's `__main__.py`:

```
from myapp import logger
import myapp.sub.foo

def func():
  logger.info(f"Hello from {__name__}")

func()
```

and `sub/foo.py`:

```
from myapp import logger

logger.info(f"Hello from {__name__}")
```

But when I run the app, the "%(name)s" field always contains "myapp" rather than the `__name__` relevant to the module using logger.

e.g.

```
➜ python3 -m myapp
2022-05-18 17:07:53,529 INFO myapp Finished configuring logger()
2022-05-18 17:07:53,529 INFO myapp Hello from myapp.sub.foo
2022-05-18 17:07:53,530 INFO myapp Hello from __main__
```

How can I get the `__name__` value into the log output with a similarly simple setup?

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial By passing `__name__` to `getLogger()`, you should be able to accomplish what you're asking. You'd do this in every module instead of passing the logger instance between modules. You may have to explicitly do `getLogger(f"myapp.{__name__}") to ensure the hierarchy is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
from myapp import logger
```

just do

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in all relevant modules.

**Update in response to comment:** I think you'll find that it's because `__main__` is handled differently - see [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages). You can confirm this by putting a `print(__name__)` line at the start of each module. In the resulting output,

```
$ python -m myapp
myapp
2022-05-19 09:19:18,088 INFO myapp Finished configuring logger
__main__
myapp.sub.foo
2022-05-19 09:19:18,090 INFO myapp Hello from myapp.sub.foo
2022-05-19 09:19:18,090 INFO myapp Hello from __main__
```

you can see that the `myapp` package is imported first with a `__name__` of `myapp` (`myapp/__init__.py`), then `myapp/__main__.py` is executed with a `__name__` of `__main__`, which then imports `myapp/sub/foo.py` with a `__name__` of `myapp.sub.foo`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it only works for modules under myapp/sub, and not for modules in the same directory as ```__init__.py```, so I get the correct output for myapp/sub/foo.py, but no log output at all in ```__main__.py``` or any other modules in that directory.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment:   it works for ```myapp/sub/foo.py```, but not for ```myapp/__main__.py```.   Why is that?  Do I need to make an exception for the first module I call with ```python -m```?